# How to load images from a local folder through a link in a JSON file?

Tags: json, reactjs

I have a folder called `images` with a number of images. I have another folder called `data` that has a JSON file with an array of objects, each has an attribute `image` that is a link to one of the images in the `images` folder. In the `components` folder which is at the same level as `images` and `data`, I have the `Home` component, in which I import the data from the data folder, and then tried to map through the array to display the images (along with other data), but the images don't show up.

```
import React from 'react';
import data from '../data/data.json';

const Home = () => {
  return data.map((item) => {
    return <img src={item.image} alt={item.name} key={item.id}/>;
  });
};

export default Home;
```

When I import the image directly at the top of the file, it works perfectly file

```
import React from 'react';
import image1 from '../images/image1.jpg';

const Home = () => {
 
    <img src={image1} alt="image1" />;
 
};

export default Home;
```

But I have many images, and I don't want to import all of them directly. I also want the images to be part of an object that contains related information.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT 1:

data.json example

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "product1",
        "price": 999.99,
        "rating": 4.5,
        "image": "../images/image1.jpg",
        "description": "some description of product1 ...."
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "product2",
        "price": 129.99,
        "rating": 4,
        "image": "../images/image2.jpg",
        "description": "some description of product2 ...."
    }
]
```

Comment: You have json, I think in React there is this data change with mutation, which allows stuff like: ‘var images = {img1=“...”, img2=“...”}; ...; <img href={images.img1}....’ basically you don’t load, just pass to html string with img location. And if you need many of them, just iterate over the json with for loop or some json parsing library (I’m not familiar with the later). But in javascript you can access object properties by string with bracket notation so you actually can have a running index on img1, img 2, img3...

Comment: @VitaliPom If I understood this correctly, then I need to match each image with the corresponding data in the JSON file by index, too. I was hoping to avoid having two different data structures for related data.

Comment: You don’t have two data sets :) that’s what I’m saying in the 2nd part. That you can match property inside the json with A STRING! You can do var i = 0; plus-plus it and do myjson.[‘img${i}’]. And put THIS inside your <img> href.

Comment: Okay, does it help? :)

Comment: And here you have just an array: myarray[$i].image; OR myarray[$i].[‘image’]; image is the name of your property, which IS image.